# How can one use enums as a choice field in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, enums

I have a model class in which I want two fields to be choice fields, so to populate those choices I am using an enum as listed below:

```
#models.py
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TransactionStatus.choices())
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TransactionType.choices())

#enums.py
class TransactionType(Enum):

    IN = "IN",
    OUT = "OUT"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        print(tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls))
        return tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)

class TransactionStatus(Enum):

    INITIATED = "INITIATED",
    PENDING = "PENDING",
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED",
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    ERROR = "ERROR"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        print(tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls))
        return tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)
```

However, when I am trying to access this model through the Django Admin I am getting the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I followed two articles that described how to use enums:

- https://hackernoon.com/using-enum-as-model-field-choice-in-django-92d8b97aaa63
- https://blog.richard.do/2014/02/18/how-to-use-enums-for-django-field-choices/

Comment: You have a comma after "IN" and after "INITIATED"...

Comment: Four lines of your code have unwanted commas at the end.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## django > 3.0 - have built-in support for Enums

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Student(models.Model):
    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = "FR", _("Freshman")
        SOPHOMORE = "SO", _("Sophomore")
        JUNIOR = "JR", _("Junior")
        SENIOR = "SR", _("Senior")
        GRADUATE = "GR", _("Graduate")

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in {
            self.YearInSchool.JUNIOR,
            self.YearInSchool.SENIOR,
        }
```

---

Problem in your code is that `INITIATED = "INITIATED",` a comma after `INITIATED` option and other options. when we add comma after any string it will become a tuple. See an example below

```
s = 'my str'
print(type(s))
# output: str

s = 'my str',
print(type(s))
# output: tuple
```

#models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    trasaction_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TransactionStatus.choices())
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TransactionType.choices())
```

#enums.py

```
class TransactionType(Enum):

    IN = "IN"
    OUT = "OUT"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        print(tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls))
        return tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)

class TransactionStatus(Enum):

    INITIATED = "INITIATED"
    PENDING = "PENDING"
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    ERROR = "ERROR"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        print(tuple((i.value, i.name) for i in cls))
        return tuple((i.value, i.name) for i in cls)
```

For django > 3.0 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices-enum-types

Comment: This is not how you define an `Enum`. Just remove the commas.

Comment: It's actually `tuple((i.value, i.name) for i in cls)`, not `tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)`.

Answer (score 213):

## Django 3.0 has built-in support for Enums

Example:

> ```py
> from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
>
> class Student(models.Model):
>
>     class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
>         FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
>         SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
>         JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
>         SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
>         GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
>
>     year_in_school = models.CharField(
>         max_length=2,
>         choices=YearInSchool.choices,
>         default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
>     )
> ```
>
> These work similar to [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) from Python’s standard library, but with some modifications:
>
> - Enum member values are a tuple of arguments to use when constructing the concrete data type. Django supports adding an extra string value to the end of this tuple to be used as the human-readable name, or `label`. The `label` can be a lazy translatable string. Thus, in most cases, the member value will be a `(value, label)` two-tuple.  If a tuple is not provided, or the last item is not a (lazy) string, the label is [automatically generated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#field-choices-enum-auto-label) from the member name.
> - A `.label` property is added on values, to return the human-readable name.
>   A number of custom properties are added to the enumeration classes – `.choices`, `.labels`, `.values`, and `.names` – to make it easier to access lists of those separate parts of the enumeration. Use `.choices` as a suitable value to pass to choices in a field definition.
> - The use of [`enum.unique()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.unique) is enforced to ensure that values cannot be defined multiple times. This is unlikely to be expected in choices for a field.

For more info, [check the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#field-choices-enum-types)

### Note:

As @Danielle Madeley pointed out, if you try to access the `year_in_school` attribute directly Django still returns the raw string instead of the Enum object:

```
>>> student.year_in_school
'FR'
```

What I usually do is to create a helper method that returns the Enum object:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_year_in_school(self) -> YearInSchool:
        # Get value from choices enum
        return self.YearInSchool(self.year_in_school)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - Django returned "'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples."

Comment: @kellyfj it should work, that example if from the Django docs. Are you sure that you are using Django version 3 or higher?

Comment: Just a warning here, `student.year_in_school` returns a string, not an enum. You have to manually cast the result back or use ==/!=

Comment: @Danielle Madeley Just from curiosity, in what cases would one expect that field to be enum type?

Comment: @DavidPiao I'm afraid I don't understand your question. But here is an answer to "a" question: Django will unfortunately never return an enum type, and always return a string. So `foo.state == State.DRAFT` will work on string comparison, but the Python docs preferred `foo.state is State.DRAFT` will not. You can do `State(foo.state) is State.DRAFT`.

Comment: @DanielleMadeley Thanks, I edited the answer in order to include your warning on it.  I also added a suggestion on how I usually deal with that problem

Comment: @Danielle Madeley, Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @DanielleMadeley The third party [`django-enumfields`](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields) returns the actual `Enum` instead of a string and thus doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: @CesarCanassa If something is copied from the documentation verbatim please quote it.

Comment: `return self.YearInSchool[self.year_in_school]` should have curly brackets rather than square brackets: `return self.YearInSchool(self.year_in_school)`, otherwise you get a KeyError.

Comment: Thanks for this. Note: I think the helper method is missing 'self' in the method parameters. Should read: def get_year_in_school(self) -> YearInSchool:

Comment: Something is confusing me - the documentation refers to the `.label` property on values, but since the type returned from `student.year_in_school` is a string, then you can't access label - So what's the point of having `.label` then?

Answer (score 67):

For Django 2.x and lower:

You define an `Enum` by setting the various options as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum):

```
class TransactionStatus(Enum):

    INITIATED = "INITIATED"
    PENDING = "PENDING"
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    ERROR = "ERROR"
```

Note there are no commas! This allows you later in your code to refer to `TransactionStatus.ERROR` or `TransactionStatus.PENDING`.

The rest of your code is correct. You get the `choices` by creating tuples of `option.name`, `option.value`.

**UPDATE: For Django 3.x and higher**, use the built-in types `TextChoices`, `IntegerChoices` and `Choices` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types). That way you don't have to construct the `choices` tuple yourself.

Answer (score 6):

An example from my project:

```
import enum

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class NotificationTemplate(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('notification template')
    verbose_name_plural = _('notification templates')

@enum.unique
class Name(str, enum.Enum):
    ONBOARDING = 'onboarding'
    TG_ERROR = 'tg_error'
    FB_ERROR = 'fb_error'

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(item.value, item.name) for item in cls]

@enum.unique
class Type(int, enum.Enum):
    PUSH = 1
    EMAIL = 2
    TELEGRAM = 3
    VK = 4
    OTHER = 5

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(item.value, item.name) for item in cls]

name = models.CharField(_('notification name'), max_length=64, unique=True, choices=Name.choices(), default=Name.ONBOARDING)
template_type = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('type'), choices=Type.choices()))
max_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name(self.name).name
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are receiving this error:

> 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples

And are using Django3, then you are probably running into the same issue I did: The "Enums" have to be embedded in the model where you are trying to use them and ca not be declared outside of the model. For example, this will *not* work:

```
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
    JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
    SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
    GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

class Student(models.Model):
   year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Where as this example from the docs will:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )
```

For above Django 3.0, You can use the above example.

For Integer Choices you can use the below code.

```
class Suit(models.IntegerChoices):
        DIAMOND = 1
        SPADE = 2
        HEART = 3
        CLUB = 4

    suit = models.IntegerField(choices=Suit.choices)
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way Djanog also supports the Python 3's auto() as the Enum value. You can use the following helperclass to make your life easier.

```
from django.db.models.enums import TextChoices

class AutoEnumChoices(TextChoices):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):  # @NoSelf
        return name.lower()
    
    @property
    def choices(cls):  # @NoSelf
        empty = [(None, cls.__empty__)] if hasattr(cls, '__empty__') else []
        return empty + [(member.value, member.label) for member in cls]
```

Then use it in your choices definition:

```
class TransferBasicStatus(AutoEnumChoices):
    NONE = auto()
    WAITING = auto()
    PENDING = auto()
    PROGRESS = auto()
    SUCCESS = auto()
    DECLINED = auto()
    ENDED =  'ended', _('Ended - The transfer has ended with mixed states')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your reference from https://hackernoon.com/using-enum-as-model-field-choice-in-django-92d8b97aaa63. The choices should be list of tuple, while yours will return a tuple of tuple.
More over i is different from i.name. Try:

```
#enums.py
class TransactionType(Enum):
    IN = "IN"
    OUT = "OUT"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(i, i.value) for i in cls]
```

Comment: Not the right advice. Remove the commas, read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to write:

```py
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionStatus(Enum):
        initiated = ('in', 'Initiated')
        pending = ('pe', 'Pending')
        completed = ('co', 'Completed')
        failed = ('fa', 'Failed')
        error = ('er', 'Error')
        
        @classmethod
        def get_value(cls, member):
            return cls[member].value[0]
    
    class TransactionType(Enum):
        _in = ('in', 'In')
        out = ('ou', 'Out')
   
        @classmethod
        def get_value(cls, member):
            return cls[member].value[0]

    trasaction_status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=[x.value for x in TransactionStatus])
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=[x.value for x in TransactionType])
```

With `get_value` you can write for example:

```py
Transaction.objects.filter(status=Transaction.TransactionStatus.get_value('initialited'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [django-enum](https://github.com/bckohan/django-enum) package makes this extremely easy:

```
from django.db import models
from django_enum import EnumField

class MyModel(models.Model):

    class TextEnum(models.TextChoices):

        VALUE0 = 'V0', 'Value 0'
        VALUE1 = 'V1', 'Value 1'
        VALUE2 = 'V2', 'Value 2'

    class IntEnum(models.IntegerChoices):

        ONE   = 1, 'One'
        TWO   = 2, 'Two',
        THREE = 3, 'Three'

    # this is equivalent to:
    #  CharField(max_length=2, choices=TextEnum.choices, null=True, blank=True)
    txt_enum = EnumField(TextEnum, null=True, blank=True)

    # this is equivalent to
    #  PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=IntEnum.choices)
    int_enum = EnumField(IntEnum)
```

`EnumField` **is more than just an alias. The fields are now assignable and
accessible as their enumeration type rather than by-value:**

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(
    txt_enum=MyModel.TextEnum.VALUE1,
    int_enum=3  # by-value assignment also works
)

assert instance.txt_enum == MyModel.TextEnum('V1')
assert instance.txt_enum.label == 'Value 1'

assert instance.int_enum == MyModel.IntEnum['THREE']
assert instance.int_enum.value == 3
```

[django-enum](https://pypi.org/project/django-enum) also provides `IntegerChoices` and `TextChoices` types that extend from [enum-properties](https://pypi.org/project/enum-properties) which makes possible very rich enumeration fields.

```
from enum_properties import s
from django_enum import TextChoices  # use instead of Django's TextChoices
from django.db import models

class TextChoicesExample(models.Model):

    class Color(TextChoices, s('rgb'), s('hex', case_fold=True)):

        # name   value   label       rgb       hex
        RED     = 'R',   'Red',   (1, 0, 0), 'ff0000'
        GREEN   = 'G',   'Green', (0, 1, 0), '00ff00'
        BLUE    = 'B',   'Blue',  (0, 0, 1), '0000ff'

        # any named s() values in the Enum's inheritance become properties on
        # each value, and the enumeration value may be instantiated from the
        # property's value

    color = EnumField(Color)

instance = TextChoicesExample.objects.create(
    color=TextChoicesExample.Color('FF0000')
)
assert instance.color == TextChoicesExample.Color('Red')
assert instance.color == TextChoicesExample.Color('R')
assert instance.color == TextChoicesExample.Color((1, 0, 0))

# direct comparison to any symmetric value also works
assert instance.color == 'Red'
assert instance.color == 'R'
assert instance.color == (1, 0, 0)

# save by any symmetric value
instance.color = 'FF0000'

# access any enum property right from the model field
assert instance.color.hex == 'ff0000'

# this also works!
assert instance.color == 'ff0000'

# and so does this!
assert instance.color == 'FF0000'

instance.save()

# filtering works by any symmetric value or enum type instance
assert TextChoicesExample.objects.filter(
    color=TextChoicesExample.Color.RED
).first() == instance

assert TextChoicesExample.objects.filter(color=(1, 0, 0)).first() == instance

assert TextChoicesExample.objects.filter(color='FF0000').first() == instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this based on [examples from docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#interesting-examples):

```
from enum import Enum

class BaseEnum(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = args[0]
        obj.display_name = args[1]
        return obj

    @classmethod
    def model_choices(cls):
        return [(cls.__members__[member].value, cls.__members__[member].display_name)
            for member in cls.__members__.keys()]
```

which would result in:

```
>>> class TransactionType(BaseEnum):
...     IN = ('in', 'In')
...     OUT = ('out', 'Out')
...
>>> TransactionType.IN.value
'in'
>>> TransactionType.IN.display_name
'In'
>>> TransactionType.model_choices()
[('in', 'In'), ('out', 'Out')]
```

which could be used as an argument for a field's choices.

Answer (score 0):

@paras
you have to change your model
@classmethod
def choices(cls):
print(tuple((i.value, i.name) for i in cls))
return tuple((i.value, i.name) for i in cls)

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use Enum, than one of possible ways would be converting Enum to Choices with this code:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.enums import ChoicesMeta

MyTypeWithChoices = types.new_class(
    "MyTypeWithChoices",
    (models.TextChoices,),
    kwds={"metaclass": ChoicesMeta},
    exec_body=lambda ns: ns.update({d.name: d.value for d in SomeEnum}),
)
```

One problem with that approach is that tools like Pyright and IDEs would not provide static type hints at all for dynamic class.