# In Django, how do I define a string value for IntegerChoices enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, enums

I'm using Django 3.2 and Python 3.9.  In my model, I define an int enum.  I would also like to define readable string values for it, so I tried

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
        BUY = 0
        SELL = 1

        labels = {
            BUY: 'Buy',
            SELL: 'Sell'
        }

        translation = {v: k for k, v in labels.items()}
```

but this definition fails with the error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'
```

How would I define strings for each value?  I don't mind if the strings are just the literal variable names (e.g. "BUY", "SELL")

**Edit:** In response to the one of the answers given, seeing this result ...

```
>>> t = Transaction.objects.all().first()
>>> t.type
0
>>> str(t.type)
'0'
```

Comment: can u share the full code of the model??

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Where do you get the concept for that `labels` dictionary from? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802616/how-to-use-enums-as-a-choice-field-in-django-model the Enumeration types are pretty straightforward about this all you need is a tuple with two values with the second being the label...

Comment: My underlying question is if you define a field as an integer with choices mapping to those tuples, does Django provide a slick way of converting an instance of that field to the string part of the tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to go about it as per [django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/) for Django3.2

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
         BUY = 0, _('Buy')
         SELL = 1, _('Sell')
```

(or)

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
         BUY = 0, 'Buy'
         SELL = 1, 'Sell'
```

Another way is to make use of [Enum functional api](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api), this is also mentioned in the Django 3.2 official documentation

```
 TransactionTypes = models.IntegerChoices('TransactionTypes', 'BUY SELL')
 TransactionTypes.choices
 #provides below output
 >>>[(1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell')]
```

**EDIT: 1**

Considering you only have a handful of transaction types (like Buy/Sell and other future transaction type possibilities like Exchange or Return), I would suggest to use [`PositiveSmallIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) which is more apt for your scenario.

Here `PositiveSmallIntegerField` supports values from 0 to 32767 compared to `SmallIntegerField` supports values from -32768 to 32767

SYNTAX:

```
  models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(**Field Options)
```

Example:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
         BUY = 0, 'Buy'
         SELL = 1, 'Sell'

    start_transactionType= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TransactionTypes.choices, default=TransactionTypes.BUY, help_text="Do you wish to Buy or Sell?", null=True, blank=True, primary_key=False, editable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.start_transactionType)
```

> __ str __ is a Python method that returns a string representation of any object. This is what Django uses to display model instances as a plain string.

**Field Options**

- `choices` : Sets the choices for this field
- `default`: The default value for the field
- `help_text`: Extra “help” text to be displayed with the form widget. It’s useful for documentation even if your field isn’t used on a form
- `null`:  If set to **`True`** Django stores empty values as `NULL` in database, by default it is **`False`**.
- `blank`: If **`True`**, this field is allowed to be blank, by default its **`False`**
- `primary_key`: If **`True`**, this field is primary key for model, by default it is **`False`**
- `editable`: If **`False`**, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is **`True`**.

For a live example you can follow this 5 part tutorial series,
[part 5: Fluent in Django: Get to know Django models better](https://girlthatlovestocode.com/django-model)

**EDIT: 2**

> A number of custom properties are added to the enumeration classes – .choices, .labels, .values, and .names – to make it easier to access lists of those separate parts of the enumeration.

As per django documentation use can the  `.label` property or `.name` property

```
         TransactionTypes.BUY.label
         >>>  “Buy” #returns this output as string value

         TransactionType.BUY.name 
         >>> “BUY” # returns this output 

         TransactionType.BUY.value
          >>> 0 # returns this as output
```

**EDIT 3** Based on updated question &comments

Brief information covered in Edit 3

- *extra instance method* example quoted from django 3.2 doc
- How to apply *extra instance method* to your use case
- Workaround function to solve issues

**Django 3.2 [documentation on extra instance method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)** mentions

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.
> Sample example from documentation is given below

> ```
>  from django.db import models
>    class Person(models.Model):
>          SHIRT_SIZES = (
>             ('S', 'Small'),
>                  ('M', 'Medium'),
>             ('L', 'Large'),
>           )
>  name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
>  shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
> ```

> ```
>  >>>p = Person(name="Fred Flintstone", shirt_size="L")
>  >>>p.save()
>  >>>p.shirt_size
>  ‘L’ #output
>  >>> p.get_shirt_size_display()
>  ‘Large’ #output
> ```

**APPLYING *extra instance method* to your use case**

Based on your updated question & comments you have mentioned `t` to be instance of `Transactions` object and `type` to be `PositiveSmallIntegerField` (an instance of `TransactionTypes` choices)

The **t.get_type_display()** code  should ideally produce the output `Buy` as string

```
 >>> type= models.PositiveSmallIntegersField(choices=TransactionTypes.choices, null=True, blank=True)
 >>> t = Transaction.objects.all().first()
 >>> t.type 
 0 #output
 >>> t.get_type_display()
 ‘Buy’   #output
```

**Workaround**

A workaround is to write a separate function that checks with int enum value and return label as string

```
  def label_of_TransactionType:
       if (t.type== TransactionType.BUY.value):
               return TransactionTypes.BUY.label
         else:
               return TransactionTypes.SELL.label
```

Comment: So if I have a single instance of transaction, how do I get the string value of my "type" field, assuming it is defined as "models.SmallIntegerField(
        null=False,
        choices=TransactionTypes.choices,
    )"

Comment: It’s better to opt for `PositiveSmallIntegerField` than `SmallIntegerField`, do refer to edit based on your comments

Comment: @Dave you also need to use python method __ str __ for getting the string value

Comment: I added my question but str(t.type) is not giving the string, just a stringified version of the number.  I did chang emy column type to PositiveSmallInteger, per your suggestion. (Also the "_('Buy')" results in a compilation error so I used the "BUY = 0, 'Buy'" solution instead.

Comment: @Dave just saw your edit which seems to be on Javed’s answer and not on your own question. 
Do make the corrections with .label property as per my previous comment

Comment: REPOST: @Dave in your case it will be `t.type.label` which will give you strings “Buy” or “Sell”.

Comment: "t.type.label" is giving me the error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'label'".  'Transaction.TransactionTypes.BUY.label' does print out the string, but I'm more interested in getting the instance attribute as the string.

Comment: @Dave Django mentions an extra instance method that helps to display the label `t.get_type_display()` should ideally return label “Buy” as string value. I have also provided a workaround if extra instance method is not automatically created by Django. Check updated answer **EDIT 3**

Comment: @Dave django 3.2 doc mentions _extra instance method_ states for every field that has choices set, object will have a `get_FOO_display()` method where FOO is name of the field. In your case FOO is type, **`t.get_type_display()`** will return strings ‘Buy’ or ‘Sell’ . Additionally you can use the workaround function. Refer to EDIT 3

Comment: "t.get_type_display" is a winner!  Exactly the simple solution I was looking for.  thx!

Comment: For the label getter function: ```lambda val:dict(TransactionTypes.choices)[val]```

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you  define choices as a Tuple of Tuple, each option being the value of the outer tuple.
The first element in each inner tuple is the value to be set in the model, and the second element being its string representation.like the code snippet below:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    BUY = 0
    SELL = 1
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (BUY, 'Buy'),
        (SELL, 'Sell'),
    )
    type_of_transaction = models.IntegerField(
        choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=‌BUY,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the consistent definition, but there are other answer for this question is using enums and I think the Enum type is by far the best. They can show an integer and a string for an item at the same time, while keeping your code more readable.see the code snippets below:

## app/enums.py

```
from enum import Enum    

class ChoiceEnum(Enum):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
    
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        choices = list()
        for item in cls:  # Loop thru defined enums
            choices.append((item.value, item.name))   
        return tuple(choices)


class TransactionType(ChoiceEnum):
    BUY = 0
    SELL = 1

# Uh oh
TransactionType.BUY._name_ = 'Buy'
TransactionType.SELL._name_ = 'Sell'
```

## app/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from myapp.enums import TransactionType

class Transaction(models.Model):
     type_of_transaction = models.IntegerField(choices=TransactionType.choices(), default=int(TransactionType.BUY))
# ...
```

Comment: With the way you've defined the above, how would I access the "type_of_transaction" attribute as its string version if I had an instance of Transaction?