# How to show Django form in template?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

I want to display countries and states in Django form, for that I am trying to get data from json, create form, pass json data to form and get state of the country on ajax request. I managed to write the process as far as I learned, but at last form is not rendered on Django template. How can I render Django form with following code structure?

My Model:

```
    from django.db import models
class Address(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.country, self.state)
```

My Forms.py:

```
import json
def readJson(filename):
            with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
                return json.load(fp)
def get_country():
    """ GET COUNTRY SELECTION """
    filepath = './static/data/countries_states_cities.json'
    all_data = readJson(filepath)
        
    all_countries = [('-----', '---Select a Country---')]
        
    for x in all_data:
            y = (x['name'], x['name'])
            all_countries.append(y)
            
    return all_countries


def return_state_by_country(country):
    """ GET STATE SELECTION BY COUNTRY INPUT """
    filepath = './static/data/countries_states_cities.json'
    all_data = readJson(filepath)
    
    all_states = []
    
    for x in all_data:
        if x['name'] == country:
                if 'states' in x:
                    for state in x['states']:
                        y = (state['name'], state['name'])
                        all_states.append(state['name'])
                else:
                    all_states.append(country)
    return all_states

class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(
                    choices = get_country(),
                    required = False,
                    label='Country / Region*',
                    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_country'}),
                    )
    class Meta:
            model = Address
            fields = ['country']
```

My Form.html

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% for error in errors  %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger mb-4" role="alert">
                          <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                      </div>
              {% endfor %}
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="mb-4">
                     {{ form.country}}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label >Select a Province/State</label>
                       <select id="id_province" class="form-control" name="state">
                         <option value="-----">Select Province/State</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
```

My Views:

```
def readJson(filename):
        with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
            return json.load(fp)

def return_state_by_country(country):
    """ GET STATE SELECTION BY COUNTRY INPUT """
    filepath = './static/data/countries_states_cities.json'
    all_data = readJson(filepath)
    
    all_states = []
    
    for x in all_data:
        if x['name'] == country:
                if 'states' in x:
                    for state in x['states']:
                        y = (state['name'], state['name'])
                        all_states.append(state['name'])
                else:
                    all_states.append(country)
    return all_states

       

def getProvince(request):
    country = request.POST.get('country')
    provinces = return_state_by_country(country)
    return JsonResponse({'provinces': provinces})
    
def processForm(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
           form  = AddressForm()
           context['form'] = form
           return render(request, './ecommerce/checkout.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = AddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selected_province = request.POST['state']
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.state = selected_province
            obj.save()
    return render(request, './ecommerce/checkout.html', context)
```

My Ajax:

```
<script>
    $("#id_country").change(function () {
        var countryId = $(this).val();

          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'ecommerce:get-province' %}",
          data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            'country': country
          },
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.provinces);
            let html_data = '<option value="-----">Select Province/State</option>';
            data.provinces.forEach(function (data) {
                html_data += `<option value="${data}">${data}</option>`
            });
            $("#id_province").html(html_data);
          }
        });
});
</script>
```

I am trying to print form.country on template but its not working. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `ModelForms` I find that this type of configuration, in which everything falls under `class Meta:` works.

However im dubious about that `get_country()` method. If you share it I can take a deeper look and maybe even test it to make sure that it's not doing anything funky.

If your list of countries is somewhat static and not too long you might wanna consider using a `TextChoices` enum type in your model attribute to limit the choice selection. Django forms will automatically render a dropdown widget listing the items from your enum.

You can checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802616/how-to-use-enums-as-a-choice-field-in-django-model) if you want to look into that, which further links to the django docs.

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['country']
        widgets = {
            "country": forms.ChoiceField(
                choices = get_country(),
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-control",
                    "id": "id_country"
                }
            ),
        }
        labels = {
            "country" : "Company Country Location"
        }
```